# Sorting nearest date with MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, date

I have a simple task list which contains amongst others a title field and a deadline field. Some tasks got deadlines, other don't. Deadlines are simply stored with a MySQL date type.

But the tough part (for me anyway) is to sort the tasks in the correct order:

1. Ascending deadlines
2. The rest (maybe by ID, but not important)

Current query:

```
SELECT * FROM tasks ORDER BY deadline ASC
```

The deadline field is '0000-00-00' by default, so this query will show the tasks in the following order:

1. Tasks with no deadlines
2. Ascending deadlines

Can anybody point me in the right direction, or do I need to do multiple queries?

Comment: Why not have deadline be null by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tasks
ORDER BY CASE WHEN deadline = '0000-00-00'
              THEN '9999/09/09' 
              ELSE deadline 
         END ASC
```

When sorting, replace '0000-00-00' by a 'big' datetime value: '9999/09/09'.

Answer (score 2):

One obvious possibility would be (in the application that creates the projects) set a deadline *way* in the future (say '9999-12-31') if the user doesn't enter a deadline. Of course, it's not clear whether you can change that code or not...

Comment: Actually, field type date is default null, so you're right. I can change the code, but wouldn't it be easier to just solve it with an query.

Comment: Probably -- if it is null to start with, then (as others have already pointed out) it's pretty trivial to handle it in the query. For that matter, you *can* handle it in the query if it's 0000-00-00, but I'd be more leary about that -- I can just about see somebody actually entering that (if you let them) to mean  "immediately".

Answer (score 1):

Is it really `0000-00-00`? The [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) says:

> "The supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'. "

I would consider storing NULL in deadline for those that do not have one.

```
SELECT * FROM tasks ORDER BY ifnull(deadline, '9999-12-31') ASC
```

Comment: You're right. By default it's null, but the code inserts 0000-00-00, but I can change this. Although the field type is not datetime, but date.

Answer (score 0):

use a where to hide your tasks without a deadline:

```
SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE deadline != '0000-00-00' ORDER BY deadline
```

Comment: That doesn't look like valid SQL to me and MySQL seems to agree.

Comment: wops, i switched where and order.

Comment: As far as I can tell he wants to list all tasks but with the ones without deadline sorted after the ones with.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using SELECT DISCTINCT